# put range name to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I succeeded converting a numeric cell into a text cell as fallow :

```
dim celdactiva as string
dim mcard as objectlist
dim rango as range

Set mcard = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("mcard")

with mcard  **(this is an excel objectlist that contains cell(2,4))**

celdactiva=.Cells(2, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

end with
```

now i want to put celdactiva (that is just a text for now) into a variable as fallow:

1.
Set rango = Range(celdactiva)

but rango gets the value of " celdactiva" instead the name of the range. in this case "D2" that belongs to the table MCARD.

2. later I want to paste a bold "X" into rango, but next to the value of celdactiva that now is named rango.Need to know the select, copy and paste statements in vba code too.

some body knows about both parts (1 & 2 )?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question entirely, but do either of these help?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8072185/1467396  http://stackoverflow.com/q/733123/1467396 (if so, which one?)

Comment: With your code, if you use `set rango=Range(celdactiva)` then  `rango.select` will select cell D2. Is that not what you want? What do you want instead? It is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: hi teylyn. I just need for rango to be = D2 wich is a range and not = value of celdactiva that is the original table cell.

Comment: I haven't used `ListObjects` in a worksheet before, it may be like Range object where the `.Cells(row,col).Address` may not be the same  Worksheet Cell you are after. ie. `Set oRng1 = Range("B5:H10")` then `oRng1.Cells(2,4).Address` is **E6**, same as `oRng1.Range("D2").Address`.

Comment: thanks patrick. I don't know the difference between choosing rango as range or  rango as range object.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Dim mcard as ListObject`? There isn't `objectlist` by default. I think you are missing the range object `.Range.Cells(2,4)`

Comment: thanks patrick. I'l try that

Comment: I keep getting values and not range notations. thanks

Comment: Don't use `.Cells(,).Text` instead use `[D2].Text` or `Range("D2").Text`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should do (1) and (2):

```
Sub SO_30768321()
    Dim celdactiva As String
    Dim mcard As ListObject
    Dim rango As Range

    Set mcard = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("mcard")
    Debug.Print "mcard Address: " & mcard.Range.Address
    With mcard ' **(this is an excel objectlist that contains cell(2,4))**
        celdactiva = .Range.Cells(2, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        Debug.Print "celdactiva: " & celdactiva
        '===[ You could have set rango here ]===
        Set rango = .Range.Cells(2, 4)
        Debug.Print "rango address: " & rango.Address
        'With rango.Offset(0, 1)
        '   .Font.Bold = True
        '   .Value = "X"
        'End With
        Set rango = Nothing
    End With

    Set rango = Range(celdactiva)
    With rango.Offset(0, 1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = "X"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks patrick, but keep getting the value of the cell instead the range notation"d2" that celdactiva has. in other words I can't give to rango a permanent range notation but only a value .

Comment: can you add the edited solution (the Debug.Print) lines to show what is happening?

Comment: hi. Finally could get variable celdactiva= to range notation like this:

Comment: celdactiva = ActiveCell.Address
      
      
      Set rango = .Range(celdactiva)

Comment: hi. Finally could get variable celdactiva= to range notation like this:                                                                                                                                                  celdactiva = ActiveCell.Address
but, when I try to put it into the range  rango :      
 Set rango = Range(celdactiva)    ' shows de range value and not the same range address.